# How to sort on sorted group documents in SOLR?

Tags: solr, solr6

We use Solr for our product search. We have two price fields ie. price and publicPrice. 
Here are my docs

```
{"docs":[{
            "price":75.68,
            "publicPrice":75.68,
            "productID":100630,
}, {
            "price":275,
            "publicPrice":275,
            "productID":100630,
      },
   {
            "price":575,
            "publicPrice":575,
            "productID":100630,
      },
   {
            "price":168,
            "publicPrice":168,
            "productID":105033,
      },
   {
            "price":420.30,
            "publicPrice":420.30,
            "productID":105070,
      },
   {
            "price":175.5,
            "publicPrice":175.5,
            "productID":105070,
      }]
}
```

I use grouping on productID field and I want always ascending order of publicPrice in group. So I made group query like.

```
q=*:*&sort=price+asc&wt=json&indent=true&group=true&group.field=productID&group.ngroups=true&group.facet=true&group.limit=50&group.sort=publicPrice asc
```

The result seems like fine (100630 (Price: 75.68), 105033 (Price: 168), 105070 (Price 175.5)).

It works perfectly. But when I sort price by descending the return is unexpected.

```
q=*:*&sort=price+desc&wt=json&indent=true&group=true&group.field=productID&group.ngroups=true&group.facet=true&group.limit=50&group.sort=publicPrice asc
```

The result seems like fine (100630 (Price: 75.68), 105070 (Price 175.5), 105033 (Price: 168) ).

Expected result (105070 (Price 175.5), 105033 (Price: 168), 100630 (Price: 75.68)).

Why do I get a wrong order if I sort by price in descending order?

Basically I need to do sorting on group sorting on sorted Items. That means I want to do first sort on normal docs then perform sort on a group and again perform a sort on grouped docs.

Any ideas how I could solve this?

Comment: In the second query string, you have `sort=price+desc` and `group.sort=publicPrice asc`. Don't you have to make `group.sort=publicPrice desc`?

Comment: @eribeiro : no, we always want to show a lower price document in a group

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you have a solution?